# Firebug: cannot find an object in DOM (using FireFox)

Tags: firefox, dom, firebug

I simply cannot find an object in DOM using Firebug (FF).

I want to see elrteOptions object in DOM. I right-click "Inspect Element" on the page, going to DOM tab and typing elrteOptions in the search box. No results.

How to I see it? =)
Thanks.

Code is as simple as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>some</title>
<script src='js/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var elrteOptions = {
          cssClass : 'el-rte',
          lang     : 'ru',
          toolbar  : 'maxi',
          cssfiles : ['styles/elrte-inner.css']
      }
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post also your HTML codes.

Comment: try like debug option -> scripts tab u can put a bebug point on javascript file once u refresh it will start debug ... may be this approach will help you out ...

Comment: @Madhu: still does not find it! =)

Comment: i think u forgot to include the javascript file plz check it once

Comment: Removed jQuery's $(document).ready(function() { }); and firebug shows my object! Any explanation of this?

Comment: @Madhu: Nope, jquery.min.js is there and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it had something to do with the browser (Firefox 9.0.1). 
After complete re-install: objects started to appear normally.